# use useRef and chartjs-chart-venn got error "Canvas is already in use" when changing data through select options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, chart.js

The Case : I want to use vennDiagram from chartjs-chart-venn and incorporate two select options to choose which data I want to display.

The Issue : when I attempt to change the data, I encounter the following error: 'Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '1' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID '' can be reused.'

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ToggleButton from '@mui/material/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from '@mui/material/ToggleButtonGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import { VennDiagramChart, extractSets } from "chartjs-chart-venn";
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Chart as ChartJS, CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Tooltip, ArcElement, Legend } from 'chart.js';
import { Bar, Pie,  } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import MuiSelectSingleItem from '../Input/MuiSelectSingleItem';

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, ArcElement, BarElement, Tooltip, Legend, ChartDataLabels);

function colorGenerator(length) {
  //rest code...
}

function CardChart(props) {
  const { control, reset, resetField } = useForm();
  const chartRef = useRef(null);
  const [typeChart, setTypeChart] = useState('');
  const [vennData1, setVennData1] = useState("Automotive")
  const [vennData2, setVennData2] = useState("Cosmetics")
  const [isShowingValue, setIsShowingValue] = useState(false);
  const charts = (props.typeChart && props.typeChart.length) || props.vennData ? ['pie', 'bar', 'venn'] : ['pie', 'bar'];
  const colors = useMemo(() => colorGenerator(props.data?.length), [props.data?.length]);
  
  //rest code...
  
  if (props.vennData) {
    const { vennData } = props
    const [dataVenn, setDataVenn] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      setDataVenn(vennData.filter((data) => data.label === vennData1 || data.label === vennData2))
    }, [vennData1, vennData2])

    const config = {
      data: extractSets(
        dataVenn,
      ),
      // rest code
      }
    }
  
    // This is useEffect I want to use to change data in vennDiagram
    useEffect(() => {
      if (dataVenn.length > 0 && chartRef?.current) {
        const ctx = chartRef?.current;
    
        new VennDiagramChart(ctx, config);
      }
    }, [chartRef, config]);
  }

  const InputLabel = ({ children }) => <p className="font-bold">{children}</p>;

  return (
    <div className={['text-center', props.className].join(' ')}>
      <div className="my-2 pb-4 border-b-2 font-semibold text-base">{props.title}</div>
      <div className="h-full p-4">
        {charts?.length > 1 && (
          <ToggleButtonGroup color="primary" value={typeChart} className="mb-3 border-b-2" exclusive onChange={(e) => setTypeChart(e.currentTarget.value)}> 
            {charts.map((chart, idx) => (
              <ToggleButton
                key={idx}
                id={`chart-${idx}`}
                value={chart}
              >
                {chart}
              </ToggleButton>
            ))}
          </ToggleButtonGroup>
        )}

        {
          typeChart !== 'venn' && (
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <FormControlLabel control={<Switch checked={isShowingValue} onChange={() => { setIsShowingValue(!isShowingValue) }} />} label="Show Value" />
            </div>
          )
        }

        {typeChart === 'pie' && (
          // rest code...
        )}

        {typeChart === 'bar' && (
          // rest code...
        )}

        {typeChart === 'venn' && (
          <div>
            <div className='w-full flex gap-x-4'>
              <div className="w-full 5xl:w-[10rem]">
                <div>
                  <InputLabel>Working Group 1</InputLabel>
                </div>
                <MuiSelectSingleItem
                  sx={{ height: '40px', py: 0 }}
                  FormControlClasses="h-[2.5rem]"
                  name="Data 1"
                  label="Data 1"
                  OptionLabel="Data 1"
                  control={control}
                  options={props.vennData.map((data) => ({name: data.label , value: data.label}))}
                  defaultValue={vennData1}
                  onChangeValue={(e) => setVennData1(e)}
                  isInputLabel
                  initialDisabled
                />
              </div>
              <div className="w-full 5xl:w-[10rem]">
                <div>
                <InputLabel>Working Group 2</InputLabel>
                </div>
                <MuiSelectSingleItem
                  sx={{ height: '40px', py: 0 }}
                  FormControlClasses="h-[2.5rem]"
                  name="Data 2"
                  label="Data 2"
                  OptionLabel="Data 2"
                  control={control}
                  options={props.vennData.filter(val => val.label !== vennData1).map((data) => ({name: data.label , value: data.label}))}
                  defaultValue={vennData2}
                  onChangeValue={(e) => setVennData2(e)}
                  isInputLabel
                  initialDisabled
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <canvas ref={chartRef} />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CardChart;
```

How can I resolve this issue?